# Change json formatting for pandas to_json(orient="records") method

Tags: python, json, pandas, algolia

I'm trying to change the format of my json file as shown below - is this possible through pandas? I've tried some regex operations but when I use the to_json(orient='records').replace(regex=true) method I get some very funky outputs. (the [] turn into '[\"\"]'). Are there any alternatives? Thanks so much for your help. I've included one line from the million or so with the personal information removed.

Some background info: The below data was scraped from my algolia database, read into pandas, and saved as a json file.

My actual json file (there are around a million of these kinds of rows)

```
[{"Unnamed: 0":37427,"email":null,"industry":"['']","category":"['help', 'motivation']","phone":null,"tags":"['U.S.']","twitter_bio":"I'm the freshest kid on the block."}]
```

My actual output

```
Unnamed: 0    category                email   industry  phone   tags        twitter_bio     
37427         ['help', 'motivation']  NaN     ['']      NaN     ['U.S.']    I'm the freshest kid on the block.
```

Desired json file

```
[{"Unnamed: 0":37427,"email":null,"industry":[""],"category":["help", "motivation"],"phone":null,"tags":["U.S."],"twitter_bio":"I'm the freshest kid on the block."}]
```

Desired output

```
Unnamed: 0    category              email   industry    phone   tags        twitter_bio     
37427         [help, motivation]    NaN     []          NaN     [U.S.]      I'm the freshest kid on the block.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of assuming that what you are trying to do is to convert your lists (which originally are just strings), and want them as actual lists.

you can do some string manipulation to achieve that:

```
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

json_file = 'C:/test.json'

jsonStr= open(json_file).read()

jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('"[','[')
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(']"',']')


jsonStr = re.sub("\[[^]]*\]", lambda x:x.group(0).replace("'",'"'), jsonStr)

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

df = json_normalize(jsonObj[0])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
   Unnamed: 0            category email industry phone    tags                         twitter_bio
0       37427  [help, motivation]  None       []  None  [U.S.]  I'm the freshest kid on the block.
```

Comment: This is super super close to what I need. Thank you so much! Is it possible to have the regex only affect certain columns? It's changing the formatting for apostrophes in the twitter_bio section currently. (`I\'m the freshest kid on the block.`)

Comment: actually it's not "changing" them per say. It's an escape sequence so it reads the `'` as is. Otherwise it'll think that the `'` is part of the json format syntax. Where is the `I\'m` showing up?

Comment: I figured it out! Was an encoding issue. Thanks so much for the help. I've accepted your response as the answer.